# Thread hangs when executing a method via reflection

Tags: java, concurrency

I have an executor service that runs new threads based upon reflection. I have one method that when run does not exit the thread and will hang program execution. I am unsure why this is, can anyone point me to what I'm missing?

Also, if any of the concurrency experts out there notice any problems I may run into, please let me know, I am rather green in concurrency....

Notes:

- The connectToFTP method will be refactored to return ChannelSftp in the future.
- downloadFromFTP returns false at the end as the method is not completed. I feel that this is the method that is causing the thread to hang. I just don't know why.
- The goal of the method is to list each file within an SFTP directory.

from NetworkingShopCa.

```
    @Override
    public Object connectToFTP(String username, String password, String host, String port, FtpTypes ftpTypes) {
        switch(ftpTypes){
        case FTP:
            LOGGER.error("Plain FTP is not implemented yet (if ever)");
            break;
        case FTPS:
            FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient();
            client.setTrustManager(TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager());
            try {
                client.connect(host);           
                client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                client.login(username, password);           
            } catch (IOException e) {               
                LOGGER.error(e.toString());
            }
            return client;
        case SFTP:
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = null;

            try {
                session = jsch.getSession(username, host);          
                session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                session.setPassword(password);
                session.connect();  
                Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
                channel.connect();
                ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
                return sftpChannel;

            } catch (JSchException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                LOGGER.error(e.toString());
            }
            break;          
        default:
            LOGGER.error("Invalid FtpType");
            break;          
        }

        return false;
    }
     @Override
    public boolean downloadFromFTP(String directory, String filename, boolean downloadAll,Object activeConnection) {
            if(activeConnection instanceof ChannelSftp){
                ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) activeConnection;
                try {
                    sftpChannel.cd(directory);
                    //List our files within the directory
                    Vector vv = sftpChannel.ls(directory);
                    if (vv != null) {
                        for (int ii = 0; ii < vv.size(); ii++) {
                            Object obj = vv.elementAt(ii);
                            if (obj instanceof ChannelSftp.LsEntry) {
                                LOGGER.debug("[" + ((LsEntry) obj).getFilename() + "]");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SftpException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return false;
        }
```

From main

```
runtimes.put(config.getInt("ESE_PRIORITY"),"RUN_ESE");
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(totalRunnables);

LOGGER.info("Executing runtimes in order of priority.");
for(final int priority : runtimes.keySet()){
    if(!threadPool.isShutdown() && !threadPool.isTerminated()){
        //run the method denoted by the property
        final java.lang.reflect.Method method = m.getClass().getMethod(runtimes.get(priority));
        Future<?> f = threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    method.invoke(m);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        f.get();
    }
}

public void RUN_ESE(){
    LOGGER.info("Running ESE");
    Networking networking = new NetworkingShopCa();
    networking.downloadFromFTP("/toclient/order/processed", "", true, networking.connectToFTP("user", "password", "host", "", FtpTypes.SFTP));

}
```

--Edit--

Following a debugger downloadFromFTP executes fully, returns out of the method and goes to close the runnable when it hangs:

[image]

Line 1153 of ThreadPoolExecutor.java shows:

`afterExecute(task, thrown);`

Any ideas? For what its worth my build environment is:

- Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit
- OpenJDK 7 (ubuntu default) with attached sources.
- Eclipse kepler

Comment: Why bother to execute in another `Thread` if you call `Future.get` immediately afterwards? This is synchronous code dressed up as asynchronous code.

Comment: @BoristheSpider As I said I am pretty green with concurrency :-) My end goal is to have several methods executing concurrently. Please feel free to point me to a better place to put f.get(), or some additional reading to help me learn.

Comment: `Future.get` waits for the submitted task to complete so you shouldn't be calling in until have have submitted all the tasks. Either create a `Collection` of `Future` and then loop and call `get` on each on them to wait for everything to finish. Or create a `Collection<Callable>` and use `invokeAll` to run them all simultaneously and wait for them to finish.

Comment: Get a stacktrace or attach a debugger to see exactly where the program is stuck.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm not convinced that the program is stuck, I think Robert wants to execute tasks concurrently but is actually executing them sequentially.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I think it may be a combination of both: I want to execute concurrently, which I am not doing, and I think the method is getting stuck, as even running them sequentially does not end the program. I'm going to follow both suggestions and see where I end up

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I updated my question with the results of Debugging - It's getting stuck at `afterExecute(task,thrown);` on line 1153 of ThreadPoolExecutor from OpenJDK 7u25. Any ideas?

Comment: That method seems [not to be implemented](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#ThreadPoolExecutor.afterExecute%28java.lang.Runnable%2Cjava.lang.Throwable%29), so it can't get stuck there. Have you overriden it? I suggest you make sure that the code behaves as intended when written sequentially, then rewrite it [parallely](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#futures). As Boris the Spider noticed, your code is not parallel. You are running a parallel mechanism in a sequential manner.