# Using reflection to call a method inside a ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I am having the same issue from this question

[Thread hangs when executing a method via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020190/thread-hangs-when-executing-a-method-via-reflection/31887614#31887614)

What they haven't noticed is that the problem is on the .invoke method.
When I comment the line .invoke method on the next snippet, the Callables return the desired "Future" values.

This is my Callable implementation:

```
public class ParallelCallable implements Callable<Boolean> {
    private Class _class;
    private Method _method;

    public ParallelCallable(ParallelPair pair) {
        this._class = pair.getClassType();
        this._method = pair.getMethod();
    }

    public Boolean call() {
        Boolean done;
        try {
            this._method.invoke(null, this._class.newInstance()); // All threads hangs on this line.
            done = true;
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            done = false;
        }
        return done;
    }
}
```

And the next code is where I submit the callables to the ExecutorService:

```
List<Callable<Boolean>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Boolean>>();


ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
try {
    futures = pool.invokeAll(this.tasks);
    pool.shutdown();
    // Wait until all threads are finish
    while (!pool.isTerminated()) {
    }

    boolean isLoaded;
    for (Future<Boolean> future : futures) {
        isLoaded = future.get();
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

"this.tasks" is the list of ParallelCallable objects.

All the Threads hangs on the line "this._method.invoke(...)". The methods I invoke are public static and also, there is no exception thrown at all.

Thank you and I hope you can help me!

Comment: What exactly are the objects implementing ParallelCalalble?

Comment: Have you tried catching `Throwable`? Some things dealing with concurrency and reflection are not exceptions.

Comment: Nothing is catched with Throwable placed on all the try..catch on the snippet